# Business books; list of annual "bestseller" titles

Tags: business-writing, sales

In a word I'm trying to find a list of "best selling business books of 2023".  or at worst "popular business books of 2023".

Or indeed 2022, etc, or even by decade would be fine.

It's well-known that it's all but impossible to get actual sales figures for books and there just aren't that many worthwhile "bestseller" lists, and even the NYT list nobody knows how they figure it.

eg https://www.nytimes.com/books/best-sellers/business-books/

In short, if anyone has a good list of, basically "very popular business books of 2023" (or other recent years), free or paid, that would be great.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a list question.

Comment: cheers @Ben no issue, I'm a newb on this site.  Whilst I appreciate I used the word "list" (which often means "a list on a web page on that internet thingy!") But I was actually thinking more of paid services as it mentions (or perhaps some solution like "phone this person at this company and ...") Also just FWIW I checked carefully first and there are many very similar questions. Cheers